# How to make visual basic read each individual item separately

Tags: vb.net

I'm very new to visual basic and I am trying to to make a functional registration and login page. Currently, my registration page consists of 6 fields, these are as follows:

> ```
> First name(textbox 1 input)
> Surname(textbox 2 input)
> Class(textbox 3 input)
> Username(textbox 4 input)
> Password(textbox 5 input)
> Confirm Password (textbox 6 input)
> ```

The code in my registration page is writing the input in these text boxes to a text file in the format:

> ```
> input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6
> input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6
> ```

In my login page, how do I get the program to recognize each input as an individual item?

So when the user types in their username into the textbox in the login page, I can ask the program to look at column 4 to see if whether the username that the user has entered matches with the one in the text file? :/

This is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to be working.

In  my registration page I have used Streamwriter and Streamreader to write the data input into a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String Arrays have a zero based index, which means you'll want to look at the 3rd and 4th index of the currentRow variable to get the username and password.  Plus you shouldn't use the [vbTrue Constant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbtrue(v=vs.110).aspx) (or vbFalse) for a [Boolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean(v=vs.110).aspx), but instead use the value of True.

Other advice: Use the AndAlso short circuit vs. And so if the username is wrong it doesn't even bother checking the password.  Also, you should rename the Textbox controls to have more meaningful Ids, like txtUserName and txtPassword.

```
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Path\registrationtest.txt")
        Dim correct As Boolean
        correct = False
        MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
            If TextBox1.Text = currentRow(3) AndAlso TextBox2.Text = currentRow(4) Then
                correct = True
                Search_Form.ShowDialog()
            End If
        End While
        If correct = False Then
            MsgBox("The username or password was incorrect.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Information")
        End If
    End Using
```